# ASP.NET MVC3: DateTime Formats still an issue on the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, date-formatting

Ive successfully overridden the Dateformat to use UK format on the controllers.

So posting seems to work for the correct date.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Previous", "TimeTable", "RoomBookings", new { ViewDate = ViewBag.Date.AddDays(-1) } )
```

However on my view I have the above, and adding a day is adding to the month!

Aka, just calling the action link with the same date will cause it to constantly reverse.

Is there anyway to apply this UK dateformat to the view as well?

Comment: @ViewBag.Date is just object , so how it understand as DateTime type

Comment: Ive just cast it as a DateTime to be sure, but it still has the same effect. The ViewBag is Dynamic, Im sure it figures out that its datetime, hence the Add days wouldnt work otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to override the culture in a common base controller which your controller would inherit from like so:

```
public abstract class CommonControllerBase : Controller
{


    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
        var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
        t.CurrentCulture = culture;
        t.CurrentUICulture = t.CurrentCulture;

        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
}
```

Then it will always be in UK format so you can have a view with this in it:

```
<label>@ViewBag.Date</label>
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", new { ViewDate = ViewBag.Date.AddDays(-1) } )
```

and a controller action that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(DateTime viewDate)
{
    ViewBag.Date = viewDate;
    return View("Index");
}
```

and it should do the right thing with the dates

Answer (score 1):

As the ViewBag uses the dynamic type the runtime will be inferring the datatype and I guess it assumes US format.

You could get around this if you used strongly typed views and declared a property explicitly as DateTime.

Alternatively I suppose you could create your own HTML helper to output these links.